# Angular material Style not loaded

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have a fresh Angular-Cli project with angular/material

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "^4.4.6",
  "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
  "@angular/common": "^4.4.6",
  "@angular/compiler": "^4.4.6",
  "@angular/core": "^4.4.6",
  "@angular/forms": "^4.4.6",
  "@angular/http": "^4.4.6",
  "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.4.6",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.4.6",
  "@angular/router": "^4.4.6",
```

I have inclueded the needed Modules in the app.module.
Added node-sass for scss files.
Also added the theming in a theme.scss

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

@include mat-core();
$primary: mat-palette($mat-orange, 800);
$accent: mat-palette($mat-light-blue, 600, A100, A400);
$warn: mat-palette($mat-red, 600);
$theme: mat-light-theme($primary, $accent, $warn);

@include angular-material-theme($theme);
```

imported that file into app.module.ts

```
import './../theme.scss';
```

and added to angular-cli.json

```
"styles": [
    "styles.scss",
    "theme.scss"
],
```

It compiles and has no errors in the console.
But no style is loaded. I have also tried prebuild themes.
Also tried to load prebuild themes directly from the index.html.

What could be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to replace some `<md-` elements with `<mat-`
sadly no error (missing component) is in the console even if the element no longer exists. or at least there are no styles available.

Comment: You can set this as the answer then, if your question is answered.